# Symfony: Lazy-load a relation from an API

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4, api-platform.com

I'm looking for the best way to LAZY load a relation to an entity from an API.

Scenario
I have a Symfony 4 application that is backed with a database using Doctrine, and in that database I have a number of tables, including Customer.

I also have access to an API that has different data relating to that customer, such as Invoices, Accounts, Products, Bills.

I need to display a paginated list of data about the customer that contains values from the Customer and from results of API queries.

My solution so far has been to create a property on the Customer entity for each related entity in the API, and then I have an EntityLoadListener class that listens for the PostLoad event lifecycle event.  When that is triggered, it checks if the entity is a Customer, and if so, it loads the results from the API and updates the relation:

```
// customer is the customer entity
// the api call here returns a collection full of invoice entities
$invoices = $this->api->getInvoicesForAccount($customer->getAccountCode());

// get the name of the property to set on the entity
$propertyName = 'apiInvoices';

// set the property on the entity
$relationProp = $em->getClassMetadata($class)
  ->reflClass->getProperty($propertyName);
$relationProp->setAccessible(true);
$relationProp->setValue($entity, $invoices);
```

This works, but when loading lots of Customers, it is slow.  And if I don't need to display the invoice data, I'd rather not load the data from the API.  Is there a better way to implement this where I'd only be querying the API when calling the Customer getter for getApiInvoices (ie Lazy loading)?

Comment: This question is rather vague, so I will vote close. Without more details finding a good solution is just guess work. Even with more info it would be very opinionated. One improvement could be to have an API-endpoint where you can get multiple invoices at once, so instead of issuing _n_ requests, you only do 1 and then merge both result sets. If you want to limit the amount of queries, you can defer loading the invoice data by combining it with the getter instead of doing it directly after loading. Maybe loading those invoices in the background and storing them somewhere is an option as well

Answer (score 0):

I believe APIP uses eager loading by default. You can use lazy loading either by configure it in a yaml file

```
# api/config/packages/api_platform.yaml
api_platform:
    eager_loading:
        force_eager: false
```

or at the resource and operation level:

```
<?php
// api/src/Entity/User.php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ApiResource(attributes={"force_eager"=false})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var Address
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Address", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    public $address;

    /**
     * @var Group[]
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_groups")
     */
    public $groups;

    // ...
}
```

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/performance/#force-eager